# Nuxt default layout, components are removed on running dev,

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In the latest version of Nuxt (2.15.7) I have error when running dev, the Navbar and Footer placed in default layout disappear, and it reverts back to the default. This can be seen at start of command, when watching the file, the  div, Navbar and Footer lines are removed, leaving just  and therefore no nav or footer.

I have not seen this before and cant find anywhere where someone has, so just seeing if anyone on SO has come across this as it is an annoying bug?

It goes from

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

to

```html
<template>
  <Nuxt />
</template>
```

in early stages of the `npm run dev` command?

---

#### EDIT

v14.17.3 Node

6.14.13 NPM

But I scrapped the layout and used older version of Nuxt

Comment: Could you share the code as a public repository?

Comment: Hi, any news on this one?

Comment: Hi no it seems to be a bug in latest version I switched to older version for now Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on this one? Do you have a link about it or alike?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, may be my machine, latest Nuxt, maybe its just my npm/node version.

Comment: Do you have a [repro], a `nuxt.config.js` file to share or your Node versions?