# Components in default.vue get removed after being compiled in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, templates, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add header in my Nuxt app in Nuxt/layouts/default.vue

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <Navigation/>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

gets changed to

```
<template>
    <Nuxt />
</template>
```

after compiling
Any code I place in default.vue get removed.

I'm using nuxt v2.15.8
And node v16.13.2

Comment: Pretty hard to say with just that. Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: Quite Similar to this but no one have answered yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829318/nuxt-default-layout-components-are-removed-on-running-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue could be your `'default.vue`' resides inside NUXT root directory (usually `.nuxt`). Please see the image attached. That is the directory for nuxt rendered files. So, it will keep getting refreshed when you compile. I had the same issue. I fixed the issue by creating `'layouts'` directory outside the `.nuxt`, which is the right way to do it.

So, your default.vue structure might look like this after fixing it: `<your-proj-dir>/layouts/default.vue.`

[I had wrongly created `layouts/default.vue` like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snyQN.png)

[Fixed the issue by creating `layout/dfeault.vue` ouside `.nuxt` directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRX8A.png)

Answer (score 0):

check your **layouts** directory's name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).